# How to return to AJAX error function from application_error?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

My code below ends up in the AJAX `success` function. Why? It should execute the `error` function. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(data) {
        if (callback)
            callback(data);

        $.LoadingOverlay("hide");
    },
    error: function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
        var t = "";

    }
});
```

```csharp
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

    var exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();

    bool isAjaxCall = string.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Context.ClearError();
    if (isAjaxCall)
    {
        //Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
        Context.Response.Write(
            new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
                new { error = exception.Message }
            )
        );
    }
}
```

The controller simply throws an exception:

```
throw new Exception("faulty");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `error` handler of `$.ajax` is executed when a `HttpStatusCode` of anything other than `2xx` is received. With that in mind, you could return a `500 Internal Server Error`, like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    var exception = ctx.Server.GetLastError();
    bool isAjaxCall = string.Equals("XMLHttpRequest", Context.Request.Headers["x-requested-with"], StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    Context.ClearError();

    if (isAjaxCall)
    {
        Context.Response.StatusCode = 500; // note the change here
        Context.Response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new { error = exception.Message }));
    }
}
```

Comment: When copying code from others I did not notice the 200 statuscode:(. Thanks!